# How to embed a 3D graphics panel (LibGDX or JOGL) into a desktop GUI (JavaFX or Desktop Compose) in 2022?

Tags: java, javafx, libgdx, android-jetpack-compose, jogl

I am working on a 3D visualization tool as a prototype desktop app in Java/Kotlin.

I need the GUI power of JavaFX or Compose for Desktop (or Swing, worst case) but I need the main panel of the window to be a high performance dynamic 3D graphics using LibGDX, JOGL or similar low-level library.

I have searched many SO posts and pages but found no way to do this so far.

Can anyone suggest the best way to embed a 3D panel into one of the big desktop GUI frameworks? Or a demo repo which does this already?

Comment: Very basic [JavaFX 3D app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621423/javafx-materials-bump-and-spec-maps/19624126#19624126).  Example mixing JavaFX controls in [a 2D scene with 3D in a SubScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8/19487494#19487494). [Fxyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) has a sample app.

Comment: [JavaFX 3D support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621423/javafx-materials-bump-and-spec-maps/19624126#19624126) may be sufficient for what you want to do, or it may not.   Performance-wise it may be fine (it is a hardware accelerated system). But, there won’t be the feature support, documentation, frameworks, higher level libraries and community you may get by choosing alternate technology.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about mixing JOGL with OpenJFX, maybe it might help you:
https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2020/04/05/javafx-et-jogl-fonctionnent-ensemble-javafx-and-jogl-work-together/

Comment: JOGL is significantly lower-level than LibGDX though, right? Like, manually building vertex buffers and stuff....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to create a solution on the stack:

- Kotlin 1.7
- JDK 17
- Swing
- FlatLightLaf
- LibGDX 1.11
- LWJGL 2

I got it working by following these steps:

1. Use the LibGDX setup wizard with settings:

   - Kotlin (under Advanced)
   - Desktop (LWJGL 3) only -- note this will be changed to LWJGL 2 later[image]
2. Modify build.gradle line:

`api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"`

to

`api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"`

3. Convert DesktopLauncher to Kotlin code in IntelliJ (open file, Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K):
4. Replace DesktopLauncher code with:

```
package au.com.brendanhill

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglAWTCanvas
import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Container
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities


// Please note that on macOS your application needs to be started with the -XstartOnFirstThread JVM argument
class DesktopLauncher : JFrame() {

    init {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        val container: Container = getContentPane()
        val canvas = LwjglAWTCanvas(Basic3DTest())
        container.add(JButton("test button"), BorderLayout.WEST)
        container.add(canvas.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER)
        pack()
        setVisible(true)
        setSize(800, 600)
    }
}

fun main(arg: Array<String>) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater { DesktopLauncher() }
}
```

5. It then launches successfully with the graphics panel in the window with other Swing components:

[image]
The source code is available here for reference:

https://github.com/brendanhillovida/try-libgdx-kotlin-gradle-swing

Notes:

- I don't know why the wizard didn't create DesktopLauncher and MyGdxGame in Kotlin after specifying Kotlin as the language - but it is easy to auto-convert
- It appears that LibGDX cannot use LWJGL3 as the backend if you want to embed in Swing (various pages mentioned this, I didn't research further what the latest status is)
- There appear to be viable options using JavaFX however my preference is Swing and I got it to work, so I didn't investigate them further.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL which also offers 3D support. JOGL can also be used by JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks mipa - I think these are viable options too, although I have a preference for a higher-level framework than JOGL (which is just a binding for the low-level OpenGL) and also a personal preference for Swing over JavaFX. Also FXGL says that 3D is experimental so hesitant to invest too much time.