# Can javafx gradients achieve this effect

Tags: javafx

I wanted to use javafx gradients and paths to achieve complex effects. I tried RadialGradient, but I couldn't achieve the effect shown in the figure[image]

Note: Each serial number in the figure represents a point, and each point has a value, the larger the value, the darker the color

Answer (score 2):

No. The built-in JavaFX linear and radial gradients won't be useful in trying to solve your problem.

The image is not a radial gradient or a linear gradient.  It looks like a [heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) or [contour map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line).

*Possible approaches*

The `Color` class has an [interpolate function](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#interpolate(javafx.scene.paint.Color,double)).  It can be used to interpolate two colors.  That could be part of a solution, though you may want to interpolate multiple colors (like [d3 color interpolation](https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate/color)), in which case you will need your own interpolation solution.

You can use a JavaFX `Canvas` or a `WriteableImage` with a `PixelWriter`. Calculate a function value for each pixel, apply the interpolator to determine a color value for the function value, then set the pixel color using the pixel writer or canvas API.

*Alternately, consider using a library*

Rather than implementing your own solution, you may consider searching for 3rd party visualization libraries that may help you.  There may be something native in JavaFX out there, or you could use a JavaFX WebView to [wrap d3.js, which supports contour maps](https://observablehq.com/@d3/contours?intent=fork) and is [usable in JavaFX](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3).  Or there may be something similar implemented in Swing, that you could apply and use in a JavaFX application as Swing is embeddable in JavaFX, if you are unable to code a solution yourself using JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to colorize a WriteableImage with the colors you need and then wrap a 3D Sphere with a PhongMaterial. Use the WritableImage as the DiffuseMap of the PhongMaterial.
This would require a 3D SubScene which may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: For an example of this approach, see this [diffuse (bump) mapped 3D globe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621423/javafx-materials-bump-and-spec-maps).